# Getting Cabal to work with GHC 6.12.1

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal

I've installed the latest GHC package (6.12.1) on OS X, but I can't get Cabal to work.  I've removed the version I had previously that worked with GHC 6.10 and tried to re-install from scratch.  The latest Cabal version available for download is 1.6.0.2.  However, when I try to build this I get the following error:

```
Configuring Cabal-1.6.0.2...
Setup: failed to parse output of 'ghc-pkg dump'
```

From what I've found searching, this seems to suggest that the version of Cabal is too old for the version of GHC.  Is there any way to get Cabal to work with GHC 6.12.1 yet?

**EDIT:** To be clear, I'm trying to set-up `cabal-install`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GHC 6.12.1 comes with Cabal 1.8.0.2, you don't need to install anything extra to get it.

Just install GHC 6.12.1 and type `ghc-pkg list Cabal` and you'll see.

Comment: Thanks, but what about caball-install?  I tried to bootstrap that and it downloads Cabal 1.6.0.2 and fails with the same error.

Comment: Currently latest version of cabal-install is 0.6.4, and it's not compatible with Cabal-1.8.0.2.
The very soon coming version 0.7.x will support Cabal-1.8.0.2 and GHC 6.12.1.

Answer (score 7):

Have you downloaded cabal-install-0.8.0 from Hackage?  The bootstrap.sh should work correctly with ghc-6.12.1.

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cabal-install

Answer (score 3):

I heard someone on the #Haskell IRC channel on Freenode say that they had Cabal-install working fine from the repositories. If you don't want to wait for the next release, you should be able to get it from the darcs repo.

Comment: Yes, the latest version (0.7.5?) of caball-install from Darcs seems to work OK.  Thanks.